# php mail() headers problem

Tags: php

here is my code....

```
$subject = "This is Subject";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';  
$to = 'foo@foo.com';
$body = 'Mail Content Here';        
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

but when i open this file it sends a mail to `$to` successfully but with wrong headers....and my hosting server default address i.e mars.myhosting.com, instead of mydomain@domain.com how can i fix that

Comment: you're using the concatenation operator for the 'headers' variable. What's the full value of the variable?  Also, have you enabled trace on the mail server, or used a network sniffer to see exactly what's actually being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this from php.net

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: Webmaster <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Add the from header

Comment: should it send a html headers or not

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do via PHP:

```
<?PHP

$to = 'email@address.com';
$subject = 'desired subject';
$message = 'desired message';
$headers = 'From: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Return-Path: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

I hope that helps some :)